# sign-in and authentication OneDrive using VBA

Tags: vba, authentication, onedrive, using

I need an example of the following (OneDrive authentication and sign-in)
 using VBA languge will used in Microsoft Access2013 File -or Microsoft access 2016 file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are going to really struggle to achieve this from VBA.  You would need to use a XmlHttpRequest library to make the HTTP calls to do the OAuth2 login flow.  That's not going to be easy.

What you might be easier is to create a VB.NET or C# application that calls OneDrive and then using an ODBC/OLEDB provider to write to the Access file.  It just depends what you are trying to do whether this would be a suitable approach.

Comment: Pray tell why all this cannot be as easily achieved with VBA?!

Comment: @Gene Because to my knowlege there is no generic HTTP client for VBA.  You have to use XmlHttpRequest.  OAuth2 interactions use form url encoded and JSON formats.  Doing OAuth2 interactions is hard enough with a full set of libraries.  Once you actually get the OAuth2 flow to work, you will then have to set a HTTP header with your bearer token. Then you have to deal with a stream response from OneDrive.  I'm not saying it is impossible, but it ain't going to be fun.

Comment: '@ Darrel Indeed. So we start with adding a "C:\windows\system32\msxml6.dll" Reference to the VBA project, etc. This is quite straightforward, actually: if you know how to handle this with VB.NET or C# then it's just as easily done with VBA, otherwise it's the same learning curve. And yes, it's fun in any case.

Comment: @Gene With VB.NET or C# there are Nuget packages to simplify accessing OneDrive via Microsoft Graph https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Graph/ and there are packages that make the authentication easier https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Graph.Auth .  I did 10+ years of dev in VB6 and VBA.  It may be possible, but it won't be easier.

Comment: @ Darrel Agreed, I oversimplified it a bit. Thank you for the clarification.

Comment: I can use Http request by using XmlHttpRequest., so thank you very much Mr  Darrel Miller for your answer